# How to release memory of JavaScript variables correctly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, memory-management

I have been processing some client side data which may be up to 100MB in total. I have been using a global variable to store the data and the variable is declared at the top of my JS file:

```
var data = null;
```

Followed by the definition, there are some functions that load data to this variable, such as:

```
data = new Object();
data.array = [];
for (var i=0;i<10000;i++){
  data.array[i] = i;
}
```

Then some operations will replace the data.array with some new data. I found that if I just set null to data before loading the new data, the memory of the browser will growing very fast:

```
data = null;
data = something_new;
data.array = something_new;
```

So I tried to use `delete` before loading new data:

```
delete data.array;
```

Now I have a question: do I have to delete each of the element in `data.array` or can I just delete the whole array using `delete data.array;` ?
Thanks!

Comment: Using `delete` is a bad idea though. If you have new data available - just overwrite it. Or `null`ify otherwise.

Comment: Why is using delete a bad idea???? Using `delete data;` is valid and removes `data` completely, Setting data to 'null' or 'undefined' still keeps a reference called 'data' referencing `undefined` or `null` thus taking up a little space (whatever space a reference actualy uses?). If you don't intend on using data anymore delete it from the scope using delete.

Comment: @Blindman67 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/zE4cOHBkAnY + google something about "hidden classes" PS: `delete` does not remove anything "from the scope". And, yes, you must be exceptionally precise when you're talking about the standards or abstract performance recommendations.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript has automatic memory management and garbage collection. If you get rid of all references to a piece of data, the memory will be reclaimed (and there is nothing else you can do about it).

`delete data.array` is roughly the same as `data.array = null` (it just also removes the property itself, not only its value).

`delete` in a loop on all array elements is a lot of work.

All three are unnecessary if you end up doing `data = null` or `data = newData` anyway.

The best thing you can do is to `null` out everything as soon as possible (i.e. before engaging on the calculation of `newData`).

Comment: Hi, the problem is I need to use a global variable to store the data because the data will be frequently used.

Comment: well, if you need the data, you need the data. If the data you need is too large, you need to rethink your design. Temporary memory allocation by calculations on the way should be reclaimed by the browser automatically.